# how to delete data in Sql Server 2012 using c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

i want to delete data in my database and using this code but its now working

```
private static void DeletePreviousRecord()
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=ABDULLAH\\ABDULLAHZAFAR;Initial Catalog=FoodHunt;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From RestaurantsMenu", con))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }
    }
}
```

i tried this but this is not working,  how can i do that, any suggestion?

Comment: "not working" and you swallow any exceptions that might tell you what's actually going wrong... great!

Answer (score 4):

Setting the `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` when you clearly use a sql text directly cannot do any good at your code.

Remove that line because the default is `CommandType.Text` (and this is correct for your command)

But as stated in the comment above.

- If you catch the exception, at least write in some log or display at
  video what the error message is
- If you don't add a WHERE clause at your sql statement, you delete
  everything in the table (Probably you are lucky that this code has
  not worked)

Looking at your comment below, if you want to delete every record (and reset the Identity column if any) a faster approach is

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE RestaurantsMenu", con))
```

For a quick reading about the difference between TRUNCATE and DELETE look [at this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1080/deleting-data-in-sql-server-with-truncate-vs-delete-commands/)